# como retornar um inteiro em python? - Python

Tags: python

sou novato em python e estou com uma duvida sobre como retornar 0 ou 1 ao invés de True e False. Mesmo colocando int a saída está sendo "[False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]"

```
a="101001"

def p_not(a):
  b=[]
  for i in range(6):
    b.append(not(int(a[i])))

return b
```

Comment: Remova o `not` que deve dar a saída que esperas.

Comment: desta forma não irá negar os valores de "a", gostaria que a saída fosse "010110"

Comment: Faz sentido, e uma informação importante, daí é só você tentar a conversão novamente para int: int(not(int(a..

Comment: Ainda assim, acho que escreveria algo como: `map(lambda x: 1 if x == '0' else 0, a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você tinha que converter o valor booleano novamente para inteiro. Veja esse código abaixo:

```
a = "101001"

def p_not(a):

    b = []

    # Talvez você não saiba disso, mas você pode iterar strings.
    # Cada elemento de uma string, lista, tupla e outros serão passados para value.

    for value in a:

        # Converte o valor de string para inteiro, depois converte para booleano
        # devido a utilização do "not". Após isso, o valor é convertido 
        # para inteiro novamente.

        value_b = int(not int(value))

        b.append(value_b)

    return b

print(p_not(a)) # Saída: [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

A conversão de `bool` para `int` é a seguinte:

```
int( False ) == 0
int( True ) == 1
```

## Utilizando o map():

Podemos diminuir bastante o tamanho do código utilizando a função `map`. Essa função recebe como parâmetro uma função que deve conter um parâmetro e um iterável ( strings, listas, tuplas, entre outras sequências ).

Não recomendo por enquanto que escreva o código dessa forma pois é um tanto avançado já que você é um iniciante na linguagem, mas é uma forma bem mais prática de se fazer.

```
a = "101001"

def p_not(a):

    result = map(lambda x: 0 if int(x) else 1, a)
    return list(result)

print(p_not(a))
```